# jQuery AJAX and PHP return true/false

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I would like to know how to retrieve a return true or return false from a PHP script using jQuery AJAX. This is my current ajax call code which works just fine aside from always directing to the profile page of the entered username even if the login wasn't actually successful...

```
    $("#signInForm").submit(function() {
        $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
            $("#loading" ).show();
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/signIn.php", // Action of the form
            data: $("#signInForm").serialize(), // Send forms data to server
            dataType: "JSON", // Take response as JSON
            type : "POST", // Send form by post or get
            complete: function(result) {
                $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
                    $("#loading" ).hide();
                });
                $("#ajaxResponse").html(result.responseText);
                $("#ajaxResponse").slideDown("slow");
                var username = $("#usernameSignIn").val();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.href = "/profile.php?username=" + username;
                }, 3000);
            }
        });
        return false;  // Default submit return false
    });
```

Comment: Just add `result.status` on the server side, then check it client side. Also don't forget an `error` callback in case of 404, server error, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`complete` fires when the call is complete --- reguardless of the result - 
I suppose as long as it takes the `response` - it's perfectly acceptable.

Otherwise, you may want to use `success` instead, but in this case, what you need to do is determine what to do based on that `response`

i.e.:

`if(response === true){ //proceed
}else{ alert("error!"); }`

You have to put that logic in, yourself -- as `complete` & `success`  are only concerned with the actual transmission of the data, and not the content of it.

Thus, in your code:

```
$("#signInForm").submit(function() {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
        $("#loading" ).show();
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/signIn.php", // Action of the form
        data: $("#signInForm").serialize(), // Send forms data to server
            dataType: "JSON", // Take response as JSON
            type : "POST", // Send form by post or get
            complete: function(result) {
                $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
                    $("#loading" ).hide();
                });
                $("#ajaxResponse").html(result.responseText);
                $("#ajaxResponse").slideDown("slow");
if(result.success === true){
                var username = $("#usernameSignIn").val();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.href = "/profile.php?username=" + username;
                }, 3000);} 
else { //the result.responseText is probably suitable here, eh? so you could just:
$("#ajaxResponse").slideUp(5000); }
            }
        });
        return false;  // Default submit return false
    });
```

Comment: Well that was a super easy solution...I thought it'd be more complicated than that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, while that fixed it redirecting to the profile page no matter what, now even if the login is successful it doesn't redirect...I hate JavaScript lol